# Is there any way to know the type of an Object?

Tags: java, android

The scenario is that I am passing an object as a parameter in a method and I want to perform operations based on the type of that object within the method.

Sample code is:

```
method(Object object){

//if object== String type print string   
 }
```

Comment: if you want to have a check with the object types you have in hand, you can use "instanceOf" keyword.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
if (object.getClass().getName().equals("Class1Name"))
    //do something.
```

The advantage of `getClass` instead of `instanceof` is that you do not need to know the class type at compile time.

Comment: Cool, so you can make a method that gets both an object and a class name string to have even more flexibility!

Answer (score 6):

Use instanceof keyword. The keyword instanceOf in java programming language is a boolean operator that is used to test whether an object is of an specified type or not and returns the value accordingly.

```
if(object instanceof String) {

}
```

Comment: Thanks,I had tried this method before but in my case a lot of comparisons would take place and I like to avoid it.I mean if I have a 20 object types then I have to check all of them. Any other way to directly know the type of incoming object.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **instanceof** operator in java.

Please check the bellow link

[Click here for an example](http://www.devmanuals.com/tutorials/java/corejava/instanceofoperator.html)

Answer (score 1):

If you want `method` to react differently according to the parameter you should overload it

```
public void method(String s) {
}

public void method(Integer i) {

}

public void method(SomeClass o) {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use instanceof operator to check the type and cast appropriately

Answer (score 0):

You can use the  [`instanceof`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html) keyword.  Be forewarned, though; this is not normally a good practice unless you're absolutely unsure of what kind of `Object` you'll be passing through.

Answer (score 0):

The good practice is using polymorphism ..

Where you have a parent class that has a property that represent which childType is this,

```
class Parent { string type; public string getType() { return type; } }

class ChildA extends Parent { ChildA() { type = "ChildA"; }

class ChildB extends Parent { ChildB() { type = "ChildB"; }

public void function (Parent p)
{
    if (p.getType() == "ChildA")
    {
        // A
    }
    else if (p.getType == "ChildB")
    {
        // B
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you plan just to print something, you can use toString() method that will be override on each different type of object ;)

just use something like the code bellow and let each class have a different toString() method:

```
method(Object object){
    // ... object.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use getclass() method instead.